# In python, how do you accept integers as parameters?

Tags: python, parameters, integer

How do you write a function that accepts integers as parameters?

I haven't tried anything yet because I have no idea where to start.

Comment: The same way you accept any other parameter.

Comment: Start with [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

the way you define any function:

```
def f(x):
    '''
    square x
    '''
    return x**2

print(f(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunction(myint):
    print("this is an integer " + str(myint))

myfunction(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python keeps track of the types of variables without having to explicitly state the type.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language

Answer (score 0):

That being said you can use type hints in Python 3:

```
def f(x: int):
    return x ** 2
```

In my opinion they are fantastic.